Api Platform - get collections response doesn't have a hydra:member but only member property
I'm developing a backend with API platform and have generate a vuetify client.
The generated vuetify client uses pinia stores to fetch the data from my API platform implementation. However, I see in the code that it expects the response from the API call to contain a property named "hydra:member" whereas my API only returns an object that contains (amongst others) a "member" property.
Am I missing something in my API platform configuration?
The generated doc proposes the following:
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:8080/files?page=1' \
  -H 'accept: application/ld+json'

which returns this (truncated for readability)
{
  "@context": "/contexts/File",
  "@id": "/files",
  "@type": "Collection",
  "totalItems": 387416,
  "member": [
    {
      "@id": "/files/1",
      "@type": "File",
      "id": 1,
      "dicomReceiver": "/dicom_receivers/1",
      "folderPath": "/data/dicomconnector/SCP-104/1705531264363/0",
      "refStatus": "/ref_statuses/7",
      "createdOn": "2024-01-17T23:41:05+00:00",
      "lastModifiedOn": "2024-01-17T23:41:14+00:00",
      "retries": 1,
      "remark": ""
    },
  ],
  "view": {
    "@id": "/files?page=1",
    "@type": "PartialCollectionView",
    "first": "/files?page=1",
    "last": "/files?page=12914",
    "next": "/files?page=2"
  },
  "search": {
    "@type": "IriTemplate",
    "template": "/files{?id,id[]}",
    "variableRepresentation": "BasicRepresentation",
    "mapping": [
      {
        "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
        "variable": "id",
        "property": "id",
        "required": false
      },
      {
        "@type": "IriTemplateMapping",
        "variable": "id[]",
        "property": "id",
        "required": false
      }
    ]
  }
}

Thanks

You have to define this config in config/packages/api_platform.yml:
api_platform:
    serializer:
        hydra_prefix: true

